# Displaying image to window using compute shader not working

Tags: c, graphics, shader, vulkan, compute-shader

I am having trouble with some code that I am writing. It involves me creating a compute shader which is called for every pixel in the window. The compute shader is supposed to output a color, for it's corresponding pixel.

I believe that it is working, as my framerate drops when I do more complex things inside the compute shader. However, I cannot seem to get the image that the compute shader is outputting to, to render in the window.

My compute shader currently looks like this:

```
#version 450
layout(local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16) in;
layout(binding = 0, rgba8) uniform writeonly image2D img;

void main()
{
    ivec2 pixelCoord = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);

    vec4 color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    imageStore(img, pixelCoord, color);
}
```

Basically all it does here is just output the color white.
It seems to be working, however it's [my C code](https://pastebin.com/raw/ChCgttht) that's having the issue.

Does anyone here know how to fix this? I'm trying to get the image to display on the window.

I tried writing directly to the swapchain but that didn't seem to work for me either.

Comment: I didn't see anything in your C code that copies the completed image to a swapchain image.  You need to create and submit another command buffer that contains a copy image command.  Writing directly to a swapchain buffer might work as long as the device supports it.  This can be checked by seeing if the VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_IMAGE_BIT is set in the supportedUsageFlags of the Surface Capabilities.  It's probably more portable to do the copy however.  Not sure about performance considerations.